# Datastage, Remove only last two characters of string

Tags: datastage

This function: Trim(In.Col, Right(In.Col, 2), 'T') works unless the last >2 characters are the same.

What I want:

abczzzz -> abczz

What I get:

abczzzz -> abc

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The "T" option removes all trailing occurrences. Since you are limiting your input to only two characters with the Right() function, the second occurence will never be a trailing char.

It sounds though like you are just doing a substring..? If so, then you might just want to do a substring [ ] instead.

expression [ [ start, ] length ]

In.Col[(string length) - 2]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the Left() function, although it's equivalent here, as it's self-documenting.

```
Left(InLink.MyString, Len(InLink.MyString) - 2)
```